# how to use authconfig for ssh through LDAP connection

Tags: centos, ssh, authentication, pam-ldap

I'm newbies on Centos7. The ssh connection is working for all user which is the /etc/passwd. That's meaning I can connect to my server with this kind of users I added 
The other users which are present in the LDAP 've got this error in the `/var/log/secure file` :

```
Nov  3 16:58:59 ghost sshd[7853]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user user1: 6 (Permission denied)
Nov  3 16:58:59 ghost sshd[7853]: fatal: Access denied for user user1 by PAM account configuration [preauth]
Nov  3 16:59:25 ghost su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user user1 by system(uid=0)
Nov  3 16:59:28 ghost su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user user1
```

The `id users1` is working and the `su - users1` is working too.

The command `authconfig --test` shows me the line :

```
pam_pwquality is enabled (try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=)
```

**local_users_only** is disturbing me but may wrong

What's the right option to give at the **authconfig** command

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I then edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config changing:

```
UsePAM yes
```

to

```
UsePAM no
```

That's working the ldapuser and the local can connect on the server

Answer (score 0):

PAM saves it configurations per daemon in directory /etc/pam.d/. You should check the sshd configuration in that directory.